# Eigenvalues of structured matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with $a_{j,j+1}>0,\; 1\leq j\leq n-1,$ and $a_{j,j-2}>0,\; 3\leq j\leq n$, the rest of the entries are zeros.

Is the following fact known:

> All roots of the characteristic polynomial, except possibly $0$, are simple
>   and their arguments are $2\pi k/3$, where $k\in\{0,1,2\}$?

(Zero occurs as a root when $n$ is not divisible by 3, and it is of multiplicity 2 when $n\equiv 2\; (\mathrm{mod}\, 3)$ and simple when $n\equiv 1\; (\mathrm{mod}\, 3)$.)

If known, what is a reference?
(A proof of the highlighted statement was communicated to me by Vitaly Tarasov on my request, but we don't know whether the fact is new.)

Edit. It seems that a straightforward generalization is true for all "2-diagonal" matrices with positive entries: one strictly positive diagonal immediately above the main, and
other strictly positive somewhere below the main, the rest are zeros.

Comment: If $p_k(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of the upper left $k$-by-$k$ block, then cofactor expansion at the bottom right gives a recurrence for $p_k$ in terms of $p_{k-1}$ and $p_{k-3}$. Given that $p_k(x)=x^jq_k(x^3)$ for some polynomial $q_k$, there could be an argument that $q_k$ has positive real roots by showing $q_{k-1}$ and $q_{k-3}$ have interlacing roots.

Comment: And on third reflection, what I thought is relatively obvious: $A\Sigma = \Sigma A = e^{2 \pi i/3} A$, where $\Sigma$ is the clock matrix (diagonal matrix with $e^{2 \pi i k/3}$ on the diagonal), so if $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector, then so is $\Sigma \vec{v}$, so each eigenvalue has 2 "buddies" (same magnitude, argument changed). Doesn't help with simple, or to stop other arguments from existing, sorry.

Comment: @MTyson: yes. How do you prove that all roots of $q_k$ are simple and positive? Tarasov used a Sturmian argument by induction in triples of polynomials.

Comment: With respect to your edit: have you checked whether the generalization seems to work for the 4-version (that is, 2 diagonals, one 1 above, one 3 below)?

Comment: I think an equivalent formulation without matrices is: let $a_i$ be a sequence of $n - 2$ positive numbers. Let $A_j$ be the set of increasing sequences of indices that are separated by at least $3$ (e.g. if $n = 7$, then $A_2 = \{(1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 5)\}$). Let $c_j$ be the sum of all products of the $a_i$ indexed by an element of $A_j$ (continuing the example, $c_2 = a_1 a_4 + a_1 a_5 + a_2 a_5$). Then the polynomial $\sum c_j x^{\lfloor \frac{n - 2}{3}\rfloor - j}$ has simple, positive roots.

Comment: @user44191: On your second comment: no, I did not check.